# Is it possible to redirect a local port to a LAN port?

Tags: ip, wlan, iptables-redirect, virtualenv

I'm using a Flask application with virtual environment. When I start the server, I can access it locally via the IP `127.0.0.1:5000`, but I'd like to make it accessible on my `WLAN` `(pointing at 10.0.0.1:5000)`. I don't know if it is possible, the fact that virtual environment kind make my server sandboxed.

I tried naively to change my `/etc/hosts` file

```
127.0.0.1    10.0.0.2
```

but when I launch my browser at http://10.0.0.2:5000, that doesn't work.
(I can still access other services on http://10.0.0.2, but the redirection at port 5000 is not working).

I'm not sure to get it right. Help will be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**
for the virtual environnement, I'm just using [virtualenv](http://sametmax.com/les-environnement-virtuels-python-virtualenv-et-virtualenvwrapper/), a utility to handle python dependancy. Then I installed [Flask-SocketIO](http://flask-socketio.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). I'm not sur if it is actually really sandboxed, but the fact is I can't connect to port 5000.

if I do

```
sudo nestat -anp | grep 5000
```

I get:

```
tcp     0      0 127.0.0.1:5000      0.0.0.0:*       LISTEN     18541/python
```

Comment: Can you describe more about the virtual environment you've got configured and how the network is configured on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you make Flask to listen on all public IPs.

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#a-minimal-application

> Externally Visible Server
>
> If you run the server you will notice that the server is only
>   accessible from your own computer, not from any other in the network.
>   This is the default because in debugging mode a user of the
>   application can execute arbitrary Python code on your computer.
>
> If you have debug disabled or trust the users on your network, you can
>   make the server publicly available simply by changing the call of the
>   run() method to look like this:
>
> app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
>
> This tells your operating system to listen on all public IPs.

Comment: This depends on how the virtual environment exposes the network - Flask may already be listening on all interfaces.

Comment: Yes it works: I'm actually using Flask-SocketIO, and I found what you suggested on the doc: Did  socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0'). That's not exactly like the python flask doc but act as a wrapper with flask and socketio. Now it is accessible via my wlan. Really really thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The /etc/hosts file is used for name lookup, not for IP address to IP address redirection. Moreover, if the sandbox is effective, you shouldn't be able to reach the virtual server from the LAN/WLAN side. I can suggest two possible ways to solve your problem, but there might be others.

1) If the virtual server could be configured to soften the sandbox - i.e., to have a non-loopback IP address, that would be the easiest solution.

2) The second way requires more work. This entails writing a simple listener/forwarder program that runs in the background, listening on the actual computer's address (but not an arbitrary one) on port 5000, and forwarding the packets to 127.0.0.1. If this works, you could use your router to forward packets addressed to any arbitrary private IP addresses:port (such as 10.0.0.2:5000) to the listener's computer's address.